# helix moving against water flow

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, momentum

There is a viral video spread showing a helix stick moving against water. For more detail there is a stick look like a spring. When water slowly pour on it. The spring like stick climbing on the falling water stream. It appears as the stick move agains lows of physics.

See the video on this link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W93cZlbKasE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dtfCdKsAdw

I assume this is a science toy which move against water flow using water energy. Can any one tell me the name of this tool or theory?

Comment: It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking without clicking on the link you provided. To make questions more accessible and guard against [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), please include all relevant information, such as the explanation of notation or specific terminology used, in your question.

Comment: I edit the question. I want to know is that a scientific toy. If so what its name. Purpose to search and buy that item.

Comment: exact same thing. but for word corkscrew i couldn't find the same toy or tool on internet. Is there any specific word for it? Even that question don't have answer.